# ElasticSearch - Boosting based on depth in a recursive structure

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Elastic search 2.4.4(compatible with spring boot 1.5.2).

I have a document object which has the following structure :

```
{
    id : 1,
    title : Doc title
    //some more metadata
    sections :[
        {
           "id" : 2,
           "title: Sec title 1,
           sections:[...]
        },{
           id : 3,
           title: Sec title 2,
           sections:[...]
        }

     ]
}
```

Basically I want to make the titles in the document searchable(all document title, section titles and subsection titles at any level) and I want to be able to score the documents based on the level at which they match in the tree hierarchy.

My initial thought was using some strcture like this :

```
 {
    titles:[
          {
           title : doc title,
           depth : 0
          },
          {
           title : sec title 1,
           depth : 1
          },
          {
           title : sec title 2,
           depth : 1
          },
          ......
   ] 
 }
```

I would like to rank the documents based on the depth at which there is match(higher the depth, lower is the score).

I know the basic boosting based on the field but,

is there a way can do this in elastic search?

OR

Is it possible to do it by changing the structure?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking... you want Elasticsearch to score the documents automatically, without the query itself to use special boosting?

Comment: Why do you have them as nested documents?
Why not individual documents with fields: document_id, title, depth?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by indexing documents in your modified format (a flat array of objects) using a [Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/nested.html) mapping and a [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) inside of a [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-nested-query.html):

```
PUT someindex
{
    "mappings": {"sometype":{"properties": {"titles":{"type": "nested"}}}}
}

POST someindex/sometype/0
{
   "titles": [
      { "title": "doc title", "depth": 0 },
      { "title": "sec title 1", "depth": 1 },
      { "title": "sec title 2", "depth": 1 }
   ]
}

POST someindex/sometype/1
{
   "titles": [
      { "title": "sec doc title", "depth": 0 }
   ]
}

GET someindex/sometype/_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "titles",
         "score_mode": "max",
         "query": {
            "function_score": {
               "query": {
                  "match": {
                     "titles.title": "sec"
                  }
               },
               "functions": [
                  {
                     "exp": {
                        "titles.depth": {
                           "origin": 0,
                           "scale": 1
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this example, document 1 is scored higher because it has a title matching `sec` at depth 0, whereas document 2 only has a title matching `sec` at depth 1.

The nested datatype and query ensure that the `function_score` associates the matching title with its depth, and the function score `exp` prioritizes titles with lower depth.